# Rails multilinguism stored in DataBase (translation by the end-user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, multilingual

We are having a dilemna about a feature we need to implement. We want to support `n` languages in our app (`0 < n < +infinity`).

We decided to go with the solution below:

```
module TranslatedAttributes

  def use_translated_attributes
    has_many :translated_attributes, as: :owner
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :translated_attributes

    define_method :translate_attribute do |attribute, locale = I18n.locale|
      TranslatedAttribute.where(attribute_name: attribute.to_s, owner_type: self.class.model_name, owner_id: self.id, locale: locale.to_s).first.try(:translation)
    end
  end
end
```

The User should be able to define X translation(s) for an instance of the Product model for example. Also, depending on the user's locale set in his profile, he will see the translated version of the attribute.

Example:

```
Product
  id: 12
TranslatedAttribute
  attribute_name: 'name'
  owner_id: 12
  owner_type: 'Product'
  locale: 'en'
  translation: 'Magnificent shiny shoes'
TranslatedAttribute
  attribute_name: 'name'
  owner_id: 12
  owner_type: 'Product'
  locale: 'fr'
  translation: 'Magnifiques chaussures brillantes'
```

In the view, it would be called like this:

```
product.translate_attribute(:name)
# or we will eventually define_method for each attribute to be translated
# so we could use the following
# product.name
```

This works, already tested.

**The problem is** when we will try to load tons of records, each one needing to query the DB to know the proper translation to display.

**My question is**: How would you handle a CACHE about this?

Another question I have is: is there another problem you see that I might not see so far? Also, I thought about `accepts_nested_attributes_for :translated_attributes` to build the translation's form with `fields_for`. Do you think it is a bad idea to handle it like this?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 2):

You could use something such as the [globalize3 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/globalize3) to implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

A first optimization could be to fetch all the translations in the desired locale[1] for a Product instance at the first call to `translate_attribute`, and cache them in an instance variable.

This way, the number of requests for translations would be reduced to just one by Product instance.

Quick example:

```
define_method :translate_attribute do |attribute, locale = I18n.locale|
  locale = locale.to_s
  @attributes_translations_cache ||= {}
  @attributes_translations_cache[locale] ||= Hash[
    self.translated_attributes
        .where(locale: locale)
        .map do |translated_attribute|
          [translated_attribute.name, translated_attribute.translation]
        end
  ]
  @attributes_translations_cache[locale][attribute]
end
```

I think that it should also be possible to `join` or at least `include` the translation to the Products in some way, but I haven't given much thought to this idea yet. I'll try to update this answer.

[1] This assumes that you only use a single locale in a given page, but you could also fetch all the locales at the same time, or any combination of locale and attributes.